# Why does this macro yield 2?

Tags: c++, macros

I am currently learning the C++ syntax and compilers for my exam.

I was taking a C++ Mock test to prepare for the upcoming exam and I came across a question which asked 'What is the output of the following code?'

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A    0
#define B    A+1
#define C    1-B

int main() {
    cout << C;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why the code outputs **2** and not **0**?

Comment: Put parantheses around your macros, like `(A+1)` and `(1-B)` and the result will be more intuitive.

Comment: Use `constexpr` not `#define`!

Comment: This shows why many online tests are bad - they might be completely outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` is expanded to `0+ 1` and `C` expanded to `1- 0+ 1`, which accounts for the result.

It would have been a different matter had you written

```
#define B    (A+1)
```

This is a good reason to avoid macros. They are largely unnecessary in C++: templates and `constexpr` techniques are far better replacements.

Answer (score 3):

Small addition to @Bathsheba'a answer: if you want to debug such a preprocessor issue, it can be helpful to isolate the interesting part in a standalone file:

```
// test.cpp

#define A    0
#define B    A+1
#define C    1-B

C;
```

and the display the file after preprocessing, e.g. via

```
g++ -E test.cpp
```

which gives (on my machine)

> ```
> # 1 "test.cpp"
> # 1 "<built-in>"
> # 1 "<command-line>"
> # 1 "test.cpp"
>
> 1-0 +1;
> ```

Note that it's important to remove includes here, e.g. `<iostream>` makes the output pretty unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple macros can be expanded by hand.
Just keep in mind that a macro is only a text substitution.

```
C
```

gives

```
1-B
```

which is

```
1-A+1
```

which is

```
1-0+1
```

which is 2.

Another thing to keep in mind is that when a test asks for the output of some obscure piece of code, the obvious answer is probably not correct.